# Unable to apply jquery effect function to dynamically created elements

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am doing a meteor app. I have some dynamic infoboxes that will be displayed in google map based on database details . I am trying to give some jquery effect to the infoboxes custom divs when the data inside it changes. The issue is that the jquery effect function is not working, as it seems the div elements creation is not fully complete for it to work. I tried using setTimeout and Meteor.defer, but its still not working. How to overcome this situation ?

```
Template.myTemplate.rendered = function() {

    //some code

    if (!rendered) {

        //map rendering code

        this.rendered = true;

    }

    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {

        //some code

        var elem = document.createElement("div"); //custom div to be used in infobox
        elem.id = i+'_div'; // id is dynamic
        elem.innerHTML = '<div><b>' +some_data +'</div>';

        var elemInfoBoxOptions = {
            content: elem,
            disableAutoPan: false,
            maxWidth: 0,
            pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-20, 0),
            zIndex: null, boxStyle: {opacity: 1, width: "100px"},
            infoBoxClearance: new google.maps.Size(1, 1),
            visible: true,
            pane: "floatPane",
            enableEventPropagation: false,
            closeBoxURL: ''
        };

        var elemInfobox = new InfoBox(elemInfoBoxOptions);
        elemInfobox.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude));
        elemInfobox.open(map);

        $("#"+i+"_div").effect('highlight', {color: 'red'}, 1000); //Tried putting this code inside setTimeout and Meteor.defer. Did not work.

    }


};
```

Thanks.

Comment: which is the element with id `elemID`

Comment: where is the `elemID` element and how is it created?

Comment: The result looks like something that can be done with css and session variable combination.  Look at how selected player is highlighted in the meteor [leaderboard example](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/devel/examples/leaderboard).

Comment: Why are you using jQuery to generate DOM elements instead of Meteor templates? Trying to use jQuery inside Meteor is like trying to move boxes around manually in a Kiva warehouse. You should check out the magic of [Meteor.render](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_render) if you need to create DOM elements in an ad hoc fashion. Also, jQuery can't select elements that are not on the page.

Answer (score 0):

As I know, jQuery object seems not have a method named 'effect'...

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it, you want to highlight the just created `div` element which is referred by the variable `elem`, so try

```
$(elem ).effect('highlight', {color: 'red'}, 1000);
```

Also make sure that the element is added to the dom before the `effect` is called.

Update: based on updated code

1. The element `elem` is not added to the dom tree, you may have to append it to the body like `$('body').append(elem)`
2. The id variabel `elemID` is not changed with in the loop, causing multiple elements with the same id to be created - this is invalid
3. The selector `$("#elemID")` is wrong as it looks for an elemetn with id `elemID` where as `elemID` is a variable holding the actual id, so it should be `$("#" + elemID)`

Comment: I am actually doing the same. I have the updated the code snippet.

Comment: no you are not, you are using the selector `$("#elemID")` while I'm using `$(elem )`

Comment: 1. Please note that I am creating an infobox to use in the map.The div element is added to the infobox. See 'elemInfoBoxOptions' variable. 

2 & 3. Updated the typo issue.

Comment: @Anoop ok I missed that... but still the points 1 and 2 are there

Comment: 1. See the penultimate 3 lines. Thats how to set the element to infobox and subsequently set the infobox to map.

2. Pls see the code. It is fine.